# BigQuery Python API: Preserve null fields during extract_table job

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have the following code:

```
job_config = bigquery.ExtractJobConfig()
job_config.compression = bigquery.Compression.GZIP
job_config.destination_format = (
    bigquery.DestinationFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON)

destination_uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, gcs_filename)

extract_job = client.extract_table(
    table,
    destination_uri,
    job_config=job_config,
    location='US')  # API request
extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.
```

(Note that I'm acquiring my table object elsewhere.)

This works, and dumps the requested table into GCS as newline-delimted JSON. However, some of the columns in table are nullable, and some of them do contain null values. In the interests of consistency across all of our data, I'd like to preserve the null values in the json results. Is there any way to do this without having to use avro?

This post here: [Big Query table extract in JSON, preserve nulls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752631/big-query-table-extract-in-json-preserve-nulls) ... suggests actually querying the table. I don't think that this is an option for me, as the tables I'm extracting contain millions rows apiece. One I'm looking at contains nearly 100M rows and weighs in at more than 25GB of data. But I haven't been able to find a way to set up the extract job to preserve nulls.

Answer (score 1):

I think best way of doing this is using query job first.

1. You got your table to extract from somewhere and run query job
2. Run extract as CSV without headers

There is code that doing this

```
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
gcs_filename = 'file_with_nulls*.json.gzip'

table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table('my_null_table')
job_config.destination = table_ref

job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE

# Start the query, passing in the extra configuration.
query_job = client.query(
    """#standardSql
    select TO_JSON_STRING(t) AS json from `project.dataset.table` as t ;""",
    location='US',
    job_config=job_config)

while not query_job.done():
    time.sleep(1)

#check if table successfully written
print("query completed")
job_config = bigquery.ExtractJobConfig()
job_config.compression = bigquery.Compression.GZIP
job_config.destination_format = (
    bigquery.DestinationFormat.CSV)
job_config.print_header = False

destination_uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, gcs_filename)

extract_job = client.extract_table(
    table_ref,
    destination_uri,
    job_config=job_config,
    location='US')  # API request
extract_job.result()
print("extract completed")
```

After all done - you can delete temp table you create on step 1.
Cost will be very low if you do it quickly (1TB storage for month is 20$ - so for 25GB for even 1 hour is will be 20/30/24 = 3 cents)

Comment: This isn't going to work. Several of my columns contain nested data types; CSV is not an option. Thanks though.

Comment: It will work perfectly with nested columns - csv is just way to output properly formatted data - as result you got newline delimited json - just change extension. I would recommend to try on small subset - just to check

Comment: Please do not forget - upvote AND accept answer if it works for - which is definitely should :)

Answer (score 0):

This argument has been raised before in SO. I suggest you to review [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233807/null-values-behaviour-in-bigquery-queries-results) including explanations and workarounds for your issue.

There are some good answers, as for example this one, from Mosha (Google Software Engineer):

> This is standard behavior of NULL in SQL, and all SQL databases
>   (Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL etc) have exactly
>   same behavior. If the IS NULL check is too tedious, alternative
>   solution is to use IFNULL or COALESCE function to convert NULL into
>   non-NULL, i.e.
>
> ```
> select * from
> (select NULL as some_nullable_col, "name1" as name),
> (select 4 as some_nullable_col, "name2" as name),
> (select 1 as some_nullable_col, "name3" as name),
> (select 7 as some_nullable_col, "name4" as name),
> (select 3 as some_nullable_col, "name5" as name)
> WHERE ifnull(some_nullable_col,0) != 3
> ```